# Help,My minecraft keeps returning to the launcher

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

Recently I downloaded MC and installed some mods. When I started the game it keeps coming back to the launcher and I don't know what to do. I made sure I downloaded and installed them right. I'm using the version 1.7.2 and I installed Minecraft Forge because some of the mods needed it.every time i hit play it closed like it normally does but the just reopens then i hit play it reopens over and over again

Comment: WHat mods did you install? Did you install modloader and forge separately? Since forge contains a modloader part, so if you install forge installing modloader might cause crashes.

Comment: I only downloaded Minecraft Forge

Comment: Is there an error message? Anything else? We'd love to help, but we can't without more details.

Comment: "I ... installed some mods" = off-topic question as tech support for modded minecraft.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about tech support for modded Minecraft.

Answer (score 2):

**First get yourself back to default version:**

1. open up your minecraft folder and delete the minecraft.jar file
2. Run minecraft and you should be able to play the vanilla version

If you just want to play with the mods, I suggest you first try out some of the launchers
[Tekkit](http://www.technicpack.net/tekkit/)
[FeedTheBeast](http://www.feed-the-beast.com/)

Comment: I would like to try FeedTheBeast but I dont know how...

Comment: Never mind on the FTB it just wont work,I'll try Tekkit

Comment: @Stopitgetaway I added FTB just for information I prefer tekkit too, just download the tekkit launcher, login n hit play! :D

Answer (score 0):

In general if you want to know what went wrong after minecraft takes you back to the launcher you would open the log tab and look at the fancy java error. If you know how to read it you should be able to tell what mod or component caused the crash (or was caused to crash by something else...).

The first answer about reverting to vanilla is valid, but for inquisitive minds - check the log tab.